# Where not to use word "to"

Tags: prepositions

> During the final minutes of his speech the speaker requested to the audience to hold its applause...

In the above sentence, there should not the word "to" after requested...
But why and how to recognize these kind of words like "request".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In this case it's not about whether *request* can or should be followed by *to*, but whether it takes an indirect object at all. It does not. So even "request the audience" is wrong. One can *ask* an audience, or *invite* or *beg* or *implore*, or even *forbid* (though in this last case it would be "forbid the audience **from**  hold**ing**).

Another valid option is, "request **that** the audience hold." But even here "the audience" is not the indirect object of *request*. No, there is only a direct object, and that is the subordinate clause, "that the audience hold."

Comment: Thanks bro... You just solved one of my biggest headache...

Comment: So basically you meant to say that we could use the "to", if the sentence was as followed-  During the final minutes of his speech the speaker requested to hold the applause to the audience...

Comment: Did I get it correctly????

Comment: No, that is not correct. Paul suggested "The speaker requested that the audience hold their applause". Strictly speaking, 'to request' means 'to ask _for_', so he is telling you that 'request the audience' and 'request to the audience' are both wrong.

Comment: @KateBunting is right. Have you checked out Wikipedia for [direct](https://en.wikipedia.org/direct_object) and [indirect objects](https://en.wikipedia.org/indirect_object)?

Comment: So what should we use in place of "request"???

Comment: The most natural sounding is, "During the final minutes of his speech the speaker asked the audience to hold *their* applause."

Comment: Ok thanks for the help... 

Comment: I might add that your instinct ("Audience is singular, so it must be 'it's applause'.") Is a good one, but usage is a bit off here. There's also some difference between sides of the Atlantic. Consider talk of team sports: in America we say, "Baltimore IS leading, 2–1," while the Brits say, "Manchester ARE leading 2–1."

Comment: The full OED says transitive ***request*** (with person as indirect object) is ***Obsolete***. As reflected by [this NGram.](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=requested+him+to&year_start=1800&year_end=2008&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Crequested%20him%20to%3B%2Cc0) But we still encounter it often enough when reading older texts (or even more recent ones, from writers who haven't caught up with the times). So personally I think I'd call it "dated" rather than "obsolete" or "ungrammatical".